# How to create a template function that adds number

Tags: c++, templates

I need to create a template function that takes the number of the values that the user will enter
then return the total at the end. I have done one, and it works fine with same data types due to 
template specialisation. But when using different data types such as int and double it does not:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class first, class seconde>
void total (first a, seconde b){
    static first m=0;
    static seconde f=0;
    ++f;
    if(b==m){
        m+=a;
        cout<<m<<endl;
    }
    m+=a;
}

void main(){
    total(2,2);
    total(1,2);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Where are you reading the user input?

Comment: total(2,2);
    total(1,2); and so on

Comment: Your function looks very. Very weird. What is the reason you're comparing `b and m`? And what is `m` and why it is declared as `static`?

Answer (score 3):

If you simply wish to add two numbers using a template function you could do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename rType = double>
rType total(T1 a, T2 b) {
    return static_cast<rType>(a + b);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << total<int,int>(1,2) << std::endl; //3 - returns double
    std::cout << total<int,int,int>(1,2) << std::endl; //3 - returns int

    std::cout << total<int,double>(1,2.5) << std::endl; //3.5 - returns double
    std::cout << total<double,double>(1.3,2.6) << std::endl; //3.9 - returns double
}
```

Passing the third data type will allow you to change the return type.

Answer (score 2):

Using c++11

```
template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
auto adding_func(const Lhs &lhs, const Rhs &rhs) -> decltype(lhs+rhs) {return lhs + rhs;}
```

example took from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Type_traits_for_metaprogramming)

that way you don't have to specify a return type.